# How to fix "object 'mydata' not found" in shiny app when plotting histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to create a Shiny app that lets users

1. create a dataset by entering frequency counts for different values
2. plot a histogram of that dataset

A paired back example of the code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(


    # Sidebar with inputs
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput("data1s",
                         "How many have a score of 1?",
                         value = 0,
                         min = 0
            ),
            numericInput("data2s",
                         "How many have a score of 2?",
                         value = 0,
                         min = 0
            ),
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 3,
                        value = 1)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the data
        mainPanel(
            htmlOutput("mydatatable"),
            plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    #show the data
    output$mydatatable <- renderTable({
        #create the dataframe from the frequncies
        mydata <- data.frame(our_data=c(rep(1,input$data1s),rep(2,input$data2s))
        )
    }
    )
    #show the histogram
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(mydata, aes(x=our_data)) +
            geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)

    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have achieved the creation of the dataset, but the code for displaying a histogram of the data returns an error: "object 'mydata' not found" instead of showing the histogram. The histogram should update whenever any of the inputs are changed.

Any help to resolve would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mydata that you define in the `mydatatable` reactive is not visible anywhere else. To understand why, I suggest you read about R's namespaces and environments; one good tutorial on it is Hadley's [Advanced R -- Environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

To fix it, I suggest you make the data itself a reactive block, and depend on it in your two other blocks (table and plot):

```r
server <- function(input, output) {
    mydata <- reactive({
      req(input$data1s, input$data2s)
      data.frame(our_data=c(rep(1,input$data1s),rep(2,input$data2s)))
    })

    #show the data
    output$mydatatable <- renderTable({ req(mydata()); })

    #show the histogram
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      req(mydata())
      ggplot(mydata(), aes(x=our_data)) +
          geom_histogram(bins = input$bins)
    })
}
```

(Untested.)

I added the use of `req` solely to prevent start-up jittering and warnings/errors in the app. When the shiny app is warming up, it's common to have input variables empty (`NULL`), and things that depend on it will temporarily produce errors until the inputs stabilize. (For an example of why things will stumble, `input$data1s` may initially show a `NULL` value, and try to see if `data.frame(our_data=rep(1,NULL))` will work.)

`req` just looks for something that is "truthy", meaning: not `NULL`, not `NA`, not `FALSE`, length greater than 0, etc. See `?shiny::req` for more details.

While `req` is not strictly required, it has its advantages. As you may infer from the table code, `req(x)` will return the *"first value that was passed in"* (from `?req`), so it can be used in this shortcut mode for brevity.

And one last soap-box: in my limited experience with `shiny` reactivity, there are few times that I've generated data within a reactive block and used it solely within that reactive block. Given that, whenever you make a `data.frame` (or `list` or ... some important structure that is dependent on user input), it is often beneficial to make it its own reactive component (specifically, not an `output` component), and then depend on it as many times as necessary.

Comment: Many thanks for your solution and tips. This resolved the error and functionality works as required. I now understand the visibility/environment problem, and thanks for the req guidance.

Comment: just to add, for the suggested fix to work I had to add a missing ')' to the end of the fourth line of the code, which becomes: `data.frame(our_data=c(rep(1,input$data1s),rep(2,input$data2s)))`